# rsync from OS X to Ubuntu failing for large (>15GB) files

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, rsync

I'm trying to rsync a 15 GB file from my OSX box to a box running Ubuntu 10.04 server. rsync is transferring ~300-700Mb and then closing the connection with the following error:

```
Read from remote host my.host.name: Connection reset by peer
rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4 bytes [sender]: Broken pipe (32)
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (397214 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-40/rsync/io.c(452) [sender=2.6.9]
```

The exact command I am executing is:

```
rsync --progress --archive --inplace my.15GB.file.tgz my.host.name:~/
```

I am sure that there is enough free space on the Ubuntu box. Any ideas what could be causing the connection to drop?

Comment: Have you tried without `--inplace`?

Comment: I did originally, but added the switch incase rsync was first copying the file to some tmp filesystem that may not have had enough space. It didn't seem to make any difference either way.

Answer (score 2):

You may have a resource limit set up for programs run via ssh, and it takes that amount of data transfer before the remote rsync hits it and is killed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you know where that might be configured?

Comment: Check in `/etc/security/limits.*`.